# HTML is not updating even after Manifest file is updated

Tags: cache-manifest

When I'm updating any files, I'm updating my .manifest files as well by updating its version & modified Date.
But, when I'm accessing webpage, I'm getting old contents from cache not new / updated. To get latest contents, I need to press **ctrl+F5**.
Once I press ctrl+F5, I'm getting updated version. But, I cannot tell the User to press ctrl+F5 to get latest contents. Please help.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version 6.3 Updated on 05Feb2016
CACHE:
../Pages/Home.html
../Scripts/Home.js
../Styles/Home.css
../Images/icon.png
../Images/header.png

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
```

And in HTML I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" manifest="../ManifestFiles/Home.manifest">
<head>
```

Comment: You local browser cache?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to store the files locally.